# How to identify PetaPoco connections same or different within a transaction?

Tags: orm, database-connection, petapoco

```
var db=(PetaPoco.Database)HttpContext.Current.Items["application_db"];
using(var t=db.GetTransaction())
{
    // some code
    db.Save(obj1);
    OwnExecute();
    db.Save(obj3);
    t.Complete();
}
public void OwnExecute(obj2)
{
    // some code
    var Owndb=(PetaPoco.Database)HttpContext.Current.Items["appdb"];
    Owndb.Save(obj2);
}
```

In this case I have  Two Database Object (db and Owndb).Sometimes Transaction work not properly because Two connections are different.So i need to identify each connect like by connect_id or Please Share your Opinion or Ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since is advisable to use the same connection through the request, I have this two static methods:

```
public static class DbHelper {
    public static Database CurrentDb() {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"] == null) {
            var retval = new DatabaseWithMVCMiniProfiler("MainConnectionString");
            HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"] = retval;
            return retval;
        }
        return (Database)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"];
    }

    public static Database NewDb() {
        return new DatabaseWithMVCMiniProfiler("MainConnectionString");
    }
```

And then you are assured that you are using the same connection

```
var db=dbHelper.CurrentDb();
using(var t=db.GetTransaction())
{
    // some code
    db.Save(obj1);
    OwnExecute();
    db.Save(obj3);
    t.Complete();
}
public void OwnExecute(obj2)
{
    // some code
    var Owndb=dbHelper.CurrentDb();
    Owndb.Save(obj2);
}
```

Comment: thanks but i am currently by checking if(db==(PetaPoco.Database)HttpContext.Current.Items["appdb"]) then t.Complete() else then t.RollBack().